# Is there a way of adding UI controls to objects or rigs?

Tags: animation, rigging, interface, add-on

In Lightwave you can add UI sliders that can be tied to any animation value and appear as floating UI elements in the 3D viewport. This lets you have HUD controls for rigs. The sliders are directly tied to the property they control, so that they follow any keyframes, and they also change any values when you move them. This means you can do all your animating through them.

Is there a Blender equivalent?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in function like this, but it's easy to create custom sliders, using the "Custom shape" bones function which lets you assign any shape to bones.

In my example the slider bone X location is driving the Z rotation of another bone (right click on the X loc of the slider > "copy as new driver" > right click on Z rot or any other value you want to control > "Paste driver" > right click again > edit driver to adjust the expression).

Then you can add a limit X loc constraint to the slider and lock all others values, to be sure the slider stays on its rails.

Another method is to use the "Custom properties" slider to drive the values, in a similar way: in this case you will find the sliders in the properties panels ("N" panel and properties window).

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm doing at teh moment, but these have the disadvantages of being kinda tedious to set up, and that they exist in the 3D space, rather than floating in the UI.